# How do Numpy and Scipy use sphinx to process the title of a module?

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, autosummary

I am writing a sphinx document like Numpy and Scipy.

The title comments of a module is shown below:

```
"""
==============================
Material (:mod:`xxx.material`)
==============================
"""
```

which is as the title of Scipy's module [fft](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/main/scipy/fft/__init__.py). The corresponding html is [fft](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.fft.html#module-numpy.fft)

I get the following on the generated HTML.

```
xxx.material
Material (xxx.material)
```

Generating the title `xxx.material` before `Material (xxx.material)` is natrual. I checked the Numpy's [autosummary template](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/doc/source/_templates/autosummary/module.rst?plain=1). Its fiest line is,

```
{% extends "!autosummary/module.rst" %}
```

and the first line in the file `autosummary/module.rst` is

```
{{ fullname | escape | underline}}
```

However, Numpy and Scipy do not have the above `xxx.material`. How do they achieve it? I really want to remove the extra title as well.

Could someone familiar with the sphinx docmentation of Numpy or Scipy help me? Thanks!

Comment: I have created some hacks to modify how Sphinx generates module titles and relevant here - maybe you can look for inspiration https://github.com/tradingstrategy-ai/web3-ethereum-defi/blob/61936e8d55f3c94cd62f516039fbaeeea906d69d/docs/source/conf.py#L140